# c# Devexpress Application won't on Client-PC

Tags: c#, devexpress, runtime, client

How do I get an application to run on a client-pc?
I finished a small application, which I wanted to start on another computer.
But when I click on the click and run-exe file, nothing happens.

Do I need additional assemblies on the client-pc?

Comment: What error is shown in the Application Event Log for your executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you attach Devexpress Dll's to application directory?

Comment: Where do I get them? I think that's it, I'm sorry, I'm just a student who just started programming :P I think I forgot that

Comment: Go to: \DevExpress 14.2\Components\Sources and copy dll witch you used in application.